# No Bluetooth Found Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth Ubuntu Budgie 20.10

Tags: networking, wireless, bluetooth, 20.10, ubuntu-budgie

About a week ago I installed Ubuntu Budgie 20.10 on my HP Pavilion 15 n004tx. I try to connect my wireless earphones (OnePlus Wireless Z earphone and Infinity Glide N120) but it says **No Bluetooth Found Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth**. In Bluetooth settings I tried to click on button at top right corner but that button is inactive. Bluetooth chip-set on my device is MediaTek MT7630e Bluetooth Adapter.

[image: Bluetooth Setting]

Comment: See that little toggle in the upper right corner of the Bluetooth panel? Click it. Your Bluetooth radio is not enabled ...

Comment: I clicked on that button, but that button does not shift to the right.